# How do i resolve this cabal error for cardano-node install?

Tags: cardano-node

I followed the Linux tutorial at

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node

and I am getting the following error when I run `cabal build all`

```
Unrecognized stanza on line 139
/home/xxx/.cabal/config: Unrecognized field installdir on line 116
Warning: Unknown/unsupported 'ghc' version detected (Cabal 2.4.0.1 supports
'ghc' version < 8.7): /home/xxx/.ghcup/bin/ghc-8.10.4 is version 8.10.4
cabal: No cabal file found.
Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal
xxx@MSI:~/cardano-src/cardano-node$ echo "package cardano-crypto-praos" >>  cabal.project.local
echo " xxx@MSI:~/cardano-src/cardano-node$ echo "  flags: -external-libsodium-vrf" >>  cabal.project.local
danastos@MSI:~/cardano-src/cardano-node$ cabal build all
Warning: The build command is a part of the legacy v1 style of cabal usage.

Please switch to using either the new project style and the new-build command
or the legacy v1-build alias as new-style projects will become the default in
the next version of cabal-install. Please file a bug if you cannot replicate a
working v1- use case with the new-style commands.

For more information, see: https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/NewBuild

Warning: /home/xxx/.cabal/config: Unrecognized stanza on line 139
/home/xxx/.cabal/config: Unrecognized field installdir on line 116
cabal: No cabal file found.
Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal
xxx@MSI:~/cardano-src/cardano-node$
```

What am I supposed to do here?

Comment: With distribution of GNU+Linux are you using? Which version of `cabal` are you using? Did you use `ghcup` to install the latest version of `ghc`? Did you `cd` in the `cardano-src` folder (the `No cabal file found` tells me you're not in the correct folder). 

In your question, it would be very helpful if you could describe every step you took until it breaks and show the terminal outputs for each step.

Comment: I am in the cardano-node folder and I have

cabal-install version 2.4.0.0

I have The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.6.5 for GHC

Comment: I followed this exactly:

I am operating under WSL Windows 10

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node

Comment: The tutorial says to install a more recent version of GHC with `ghcup install ghc 8.10.4` and `ghcup set ghc 8.10.4`. Did you do that?

Comment: I have version 8.6.5 set

I enter set ghc 8.10.4 but it still shows 8.6.5 ( ghc --version )

It also says GHC ver 8.10.4 already installed;

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/RQf88bN

Comment: thats a screen shot of the version

Comment: The docs say that the command to switch GHC version is `ghcup set ghc 8.10.4`. You forgot the `ghcup`.

Comment: Same error

https://imgur.com/a/sqwowMo

Comment: the GHC version also still remain 8.6.5... that didnt change

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZAlT0Tb

Comment: I unisntalled it and reinstalled it and still get the same 8.6.5 version... it wont go to 8.10.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129223/discussion-between-kolam-and-dino-anastos).

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. got it figured out. It was path related. Make sure to add /home/xxx/.ghcup/bin to your path.. it needs to be prepended on the path to make sure you are picking up the correct version PATH=/home/xxx/.ghcup/bin:$PATH